# I need more ideas with javascript and html to make it more clean

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I made a project that you can use to create elements in the page as you write (type of ele and no. of them)

I think the code is not that clean. and it needs more developments, please write and idea or any change that can make the code more great, give a better output or even make the project more simple to read.

```js
let st = document.querySelector("input:nth-child(1)");
let nd = document.querySelector("input:nth-child(2)");
let rd = document.querySelector("input:nth-child(3)");


document.querySelector("[name='create']").onclick = function(e) {
  //  console.log("prevent")
  e.preventDefault()

  document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "";

  if (document.querySelector("select").selectedIndex === 0) {
    myselected = "div"
  } else if (document.querySelector("select").selectedIndex === 1) {
    myselected = "section"
  } else {
    myselected = "p"

  }
  for (i = 0; i < st.value; i++) {

    let di = document.createElement(myselected);
    di.setAttribute("id", `id-${i+1}`)


    di.textContent = nd.value;
    document.querySelector("div").appendChild(di)
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 70%;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

select {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 82%;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

form * {
  margin: 10px;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input:last-child {
  background-color: burlywood;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.results {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(140px, 1fr));
  color: white;
  gap: 10px 15px;
}

.results * {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="number" name="elements" class="input" placeholder="Number Of Elements" />

  <input type="text" name="texts" class="input" placeholder="Elements Text" />

  <select name="type" class="input">
    <option value="Div">Div</option>
    <option value="Section">Section</option>
    <option value="p">Paragraph</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" name="create" value="Create" />
</form>
<div class="results"></div>

<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: link of project: https://codepen.io/emadbakry/pen/mdxwYYX

Comment: The only thing I can really suggest is to make your variable names better. I have no idea what the two letters stand for on each variable.

Comment: i personally declare global js variables as `var` and local variables as `let`. variable names should describe whats in them, if you're looking for short names, write a comment to the declaration (f.e. `let ts = document.getElementById('txtTS').value; // get timestamp from form field`. a (configured) code formatter ensures better readability. use `addEventListener` for registering events instead of `.onlick`. And finally, I think `codereview.stackexchange.com` might be a better place for this